# Monitor console output

Tags: linux, console, stdout

I have a program, lets call if 'foo'
Foo works fine for a random amount of time during which it announces its progress on the console.

But after sometimes it stops giving any output. At this point I have to manually close the program (ctrl + c) and start it again.

I would like to know if there is a way to monitor console output of a program and in case there is no output for a certain duration of time take some action.

Platform is linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this on Internet about a command called watch.

Name

watch - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen

Synopsis

watch [-dhvt] [-n ] [--differences[=cumulative]] [--help] [--interval=] [--no-title] [--version] 
Description

watch runs command repeatedly, displaying its output (the first screenfull). This allows you to watch the program output change over time. By default, the program is run every 2 seconds; use -n or --interval to specify a different interval.

The -d or --differences flag will highlight the differences between successive updates. The --cumulative option makes highlighting "sticky", presenting a running display of all positions that have ever changed. [...]

watch will run until interrupted.